# C: compiling C++ code in C

Tags: c++, c, memory-address, mingw32, initializer

I'm trying to export some C++ code in a C project...
Actually I'm stuck with the following problem:

```
_CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fnCreateToolhelp32Snapshot = (_CreateToolhelp32Snapshot) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(L"kernel32"), "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot");
_Thread32First fnThread32First = (_Thread32First)  GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32"), "Thread32First");
_Thread32Next fnThread32Next = (_Thread32Next) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32"), "Thread32Next");
```

I'm saving the memory address of the three functions ("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot", "Thread32First" and "Thread32First") in three objects in C programming... I'm compiling with mingw under Ubuntu 13.04 and I get this error:

```
(row 1): error: initializer element is not constant
(row 2): error: initializer element is not constant
(row 3): error: initializer element is not constant
```

I know that in C the address function are not considered as constant values, but will be very helpful find the way to resolve this constraint...

Thanks in advance for any suggestion...

Comment: `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32"), "Thread32First");` and others are Win32 API functions, and I don't think you will have any luck compiling this in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please show some real code, the *actual* and *unedited* errors, and point out where in the code those errors are. And please *edit your question* to do it, do not post it as a comment.

Comment: I don't really see anything here that's c++ specific.

Comment: You must be using global variables. Use an initialize function to set those values, before using it elsewhere. In standard c, you cannot execute code (like calling GetProcAddress function) before entering main.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg & Nemanja: MinGW provides a cross-compiler for Linux hosts / Windows targets. It's quite common to program on Linux and use that cross-compiler to build the Windows binaries.

Comment: @syam Ah okay, didn't really know about the cross-compiling thing.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using global variables. Use an initialize function to set those values, before using it elsewhere. In standard c, you cannot execute code (like calling GetProcAddress function) before entering main.

```
_CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fnCreateToolhelp32Snapshot;
_Thread32First fnThread32First;
_Thread32Next fnThread32Next;

void initialize()
{
    fnCreateToolhelp32Snapshot = (_CreateToolhelp32Snapshot) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(L"kernel32"), "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot");
    fnThread32First = (_Thread32First)  GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32"), "Thread32First");
    fnThread32Next = (_Thread32Next) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32"), "Thread32Next");
}

int main()
{
    initialize();
    ...
}
```